# Xcode 8 - How does one implement UIPageViewController completely in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, uipageviewcontroller

I see in xcode 8 that I have the ability to drag in a UIPageviewcontroller into the storyboard. How can I connect the static view controllers to the page view controller in storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I connect the static view controllers to the page view controller in storyboard?

You can't. There is no such thing as "static view controllers" with a page view controller. It is not like a tab bar controller, for example. And it has no "relationship" segue for setting even its *initial* child. All child view controller management of a page view controller must be done in code through its `dataSource`, regardless of how it is instantiated.